# A way to begin learning financial Mathematical modelling with help of modelling software

Tags: self-learning, finance, mathematical-modeling

I would like to begin self studying in modelling financial situations where I have at least two conditions for the book before I begin:

(1) There should be some explicit examples here and there, but it the Mathematical information should be somewhat dense since I dont't really like reading long paragraphs consisting of solely words.

(2) I want to learn how to implement my models in e.g. MATLAB or some other common used modelling software.

I've come across "Financial Modelling: Theory, Implementation and Practice with MATLAB Source" by Daniel Wetterau and Joerg Kienitz. Also, "Foundations of Computational Finance with MATLAB" by Ed McCarthy.

Any opinions on these book? They are both very recently published (2013 and 2018) so I guess that's fairly up to date. Do you suggest other books that satisfy my conditions listed above?

Comment: @YuriyS I know about R. I've used it in a statistical data analysis course and I think it's an awful software program because it does not show code in a very clear way whereas MATLAB _is_ well-organised. However, I don't ask this question because I'm too lazy to search for such books (which I'm not), but to ask for an experts' opinion on some books since I don't want to waste time reading 700 pages of non-sense.